# CFG - How can I describe a language that dictates a word and its opposite?

Tags: context-free

I have this question from my Automata class and I am unsure if there's a way to do this.
Assuming u,v ∈ {0,1}* and at every character in the word u, the character at the same position in the word v is the opposite of it.

#### Example :

if u is 0011 , v is 1100

if u is 0011011010 , v is 1100100101

I was first going with L = { uv | u,v ∈ {0,1}* and v=(u')} but I am not sure if this describes what I am saying.

Please help me understand this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term used to describe such a concept is called "string complement". Your language can be defined as:

$L=\{ uv | u, v \in \{0,1\}^* \wedge v=u' \}$

Or simply:

$L=\{ uu' | u \in \{0,1\}^* \}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was my initial thought as well.